# color dynamically a menu PNG image

Tags: css, png

I am using an modern menu style that includes in the left and right sides 2 PNG images which gives a 3d look and feel to the menu.

As i want to make my site style customisable i need those images also to change their color based on clients desire of color.

My problem is i have no idea how to accomplish this.

I found something that shows with an smiley the thing i mean but in my case its not a css created smiley but an png image ( http://lab.artlung.com/css3-smiley/ )

Thank you.

Comment: You should present you PNG. Possible workaround are: A) using SVG for the images and changing th color via CSS; B) using font icons and change the color via CSS; C) create the colored PNG on the server, based on request parameters that specify the colors; D) make use of PNG transparency and use background colors to change the image color.

Comment: It strongly depends on image you have. Possibly you can leave something transparent and simply change `background-color` with css. Or you may try to generate images for each color on server. Or you may create few predefined color schemes and prepare images for each of them. Another way is to check if you can use css3 (gradient, rounded corners, shadows etc.) to create 3d look without using PNG

Comment: Well the images i am trying to color are simillar with the little green or blue image in the left side of the title or login. As you can see it consists of 2 colors : the green ( blue ) color and a darker shade underneath. Oh and yes it would be nice if i give the link to the images ... http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/css-multi-purpose-dropdown_thumb.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to style the rounded corners with border-radius. To create the little triangle, you CAN make a css triangle ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TccZ9/)) and you can style that triangle with some gradients for a 3d-ish effect! Just put the little triangle below the bottom left of the rounded-cornered rectangle and voila! Here's your 3D effect whithout png's!

code for the triangle:

CSS:

```
.arrow-left {
margin-left:50px;
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; 

border-right:50px solid blue; 
transform:rotate(135deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(135deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(135deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(135deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(135deg); /* Opera */
```

}​

HTML

```
<div class="arrow-left"></div>​
```